# How to add a TextViewPreference

Tags: android, preferencescreen

Is there a way to add a TextView into a PreferenceScreen. 
I tryed somethink like

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="key"
            android:selectable="false"
            android:summary="summary"
            android:title="title" >
        </EditTextPreference>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

The idea is to set the EditText not selectable. But as I suspect, this isn't very elegant.

Comment: So, you want only a description? Here's the PreferenceScreen [reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)

Comment: My Problem is, there are things like CheckBoxPreference, DialogPreference, EditTextPreference, ListPreference etc. but no **TextViewPreference** and I think just set the selectable of an Edittext to false isn't very elegant, is it?

Comment: If it works for you...

Comment: Set enabled to false too.